# Redirect and show Slim Flash message after mail sends/fails

Tags: php, slim

I am new to Slim. All has been fine but I tried to introduce the Slim-Flash package and wanted to make use of notifying my users when a contact form message sends or fails.

Im using the standard method of the PhpMailer. To keep my routes clean I created a class to handle the mail which all works great:

```
class Mailer
{
   public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) use ($app) {
   // SMTP & Fields
   }
}
```

Upon the success I wanting to perform a redirect and show my slim messages like so:

```
$this->flash->addMessage('global', 'Message sent!');
return $response->withRedirect($app->router->pathFor('contact'));
```

However, when I try to perform the action I am confronted with the following error:

```
Call to a member function getContainer() on null
```

I am fairly new and I am clearly missing something here - any tips would be really helpful.

This is the full trace:

```
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Applications/M...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(89): class_exists('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(67): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveCallable('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45): Slim\CallableResolver->resolve('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(351): Slim\Routable->resolveCallable('App\\Mail\\Mailer')
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(334): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(515): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#11 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/csrf/src/Guard.php(171): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 [internal function]: Slim\Csrf\Guard->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#13 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(43): call_user_func_array(Object(Slim\Csrf\Guard), Array)
#14 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#15 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func(Object(Slim\DeferredCallable), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Object(Slim\App))
#16 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#17 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(406): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#18 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(314): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#19 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/portalSlim/public/index.php(7): Slim\App->run()
#20 {main}
```

Comment: can you provide the full stack trace instead of the exception message ?

Comment: @azjezz There you go :)

Comment: Where did you put the second part of code? What is `$this` in `$this->flash`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `use` keyword to let `__invoke` method (which is a member of `Mailer` class, not an [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) have access to `$app` like

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) use ($app)
```

does not do what you expect and will raise a syntax error. Slim passes the container instance to your class constructor whenever it requires to create a new instance of your class, so your `Mailer` class should have a `__construct` method accepting a `Psr\Container\ContainerInterface` parameter. Then you can retrieve the router from the container (`$this->continer->router` instead of `$app->router`):

```
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface

class Mailer
{
   protected $container;

   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }
   public function __invoke($request, $response, $args) {
       $this->container->flash->addMessage('global', 'Message sent!');
       return $response->withRedirect($this->container->router->pathFor('contact'));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, all is well up until I try to `use ($app)` it tells me there is a syntax error but there isn't as far as I can see...

Comment: This is something different than what you originally stated in our question. Your question is about the error `Call to a member function getContainer() on null`. But about the syntax error, there actually _is_ a syntax error in your code because you can't use `use` keyword when defining class methods. Did you try my solution to let `__invoke` method have access to dependency injection container?